# Drop-down menu: alternative to Superfish?

Tags: plugin, navigation, menu

In the past, I have been relying on [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) to build navigation on public sites.

Superfish is a solid plugin and is very useful when you need to support older browsers. However its intricated css is hard to customize.

Are there other plugins that offer drop-down navigation and would be easier to customize? At this point I wouldn't care if they don't support IE 6 or IE 7.

Comment: Voting to close. [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is hundreds to choose from and its impossible to advise you which one is the best since its down to your personal skills and preference. I have however left you a load of that you can choose from should you want to move away from superfish. Personally my advice would to move away from building sites using any of the below and move over to using a responsive framework that comes with such menus, not only does this mean your using HTML5 and better markups - it comes with the added bonus of being responsive. These frameworks are available in static and CMS form so your not limited.

**Pre-Built Menus using jQuery and CSS**

- [Apycom Menus](http://apycom.com/)
- [A Different Top NAV](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/a-different-top-navigation/)
- [jdMenu](http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/plugins/jdMenu/)
- [Fancy Drop Down Menus Using CSS and JQuery](http://www.99points.info/2010/09/fancy-menus-using-jquery-and-css/)
- [FormBox – A jQuery & CSS3 Drop-Down Menu With Integrated Forms](http://addyosmani.com/blog/formbox/)
- [Sexy Drop Down Menu jQuery/CSS](http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/drop-down-menu-jquery-css.html)
- [Smooth Navigational Menu v2.0](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm)
- [Simply jQuery Drop Downs](http://css-tricks.com/simple-jquery-dropdowns/)
- [Another Simply jQuery Drop Down Menu](http://www.webchiefdesign.co.uk/blog/simple-jquery-dropdown-menu/index.php)
- [Professional Drop Down](http://www.stunicholls.com/menu/pro_dropdown_2.html)

**Create Your Own Menus**

- [Create Your Own Menu using CSS + jQuery](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/create-a-multilevel-dropdown-menu-with-css-and-improve-it-via-jquery)
- [How To Create Your Own Drop Down Nav Using HTML5, CSS and jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-a-drop-down-nav-menu-with-html5-css3-and-jquery/)
- [Create a Simple Drop down Menu](http://www.instantshift.com/2010/07/16/create-simple-dropdown-menu-using-jquery/)
- [Create a Vimeo like top Navigation using jQuery](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/create-vimeo-like-top-navigation/)

**Frameworks with Menus**

- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)
- [Foundation 3 by Zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- [***For Even More Checkout This Answer I left on Another Webmasters Thread***](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42922/as-a-beginner-i-would-like-to-know-which-should-be-the-markup-language-to-start/42925#42925)

Comment: Thanks for this selection! Right, there are hundreds to choose from, but the few I tried showed poor cross-browser compatibility (e.g. IE 8 support). I agree that I should move over to a responsive framework.